# Splitting file into smaller files, working script, but need some tweaks

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have a script here that looks for a delimiter in a text file with several reports in it.  The script saves each individual report as it's own text document. The tweaks I'm trying to achieve are:

In the middle of the data of each page there is - `SPEC #: RX:<string>.`  I want that string to be saved as the filename.

it currently saves from the delimiter down to the next one. This ignores the first report and grabs every one after. I want it to go from the delimiter UP to the next one, but I haven't figured out how to achieve that.

```
$InPC = "C:\Users\path"
Get-ChildItem -Path $InPC -Filter *.txt | ForEach-Object -Process {
$basename= $_.BaseName
$m = ( ( Get-Content $_.FullName | Where { $_ | Select-String "END OF 
REPORT" -Quiet } | Measure-Object | ForEach-Object { $_.Count } ) -ge 2)
$a = 1
if ($m) {
Get-Content $_.FullName | % {

If ($_ -match "END OF REPORT") {
$OutputFile = "$InPC\$basename _$a.txt"
$a++
}
Add-Content $OutputFile $_
}
Remove-Item $_.FullName
}
}
```

This works, as stated it outputs the file with `END OF REPORT` on top, the first report in the file gets omitted as it does not have `END OF REPORT` above it.

Edited code:

```
$InPC = 'C:\Path' #

ForEach($File in Get-ChildItem -Path $InPC -Filter *.txt){
    $RepNum=0
    ForEach($Report in (([IO.File]::ReadAllText('C:\Path'$File) -split 'END OF REPORT\r?\n?' -ne '')){
        if ($Report -match 'SPEC #: RX:(?<ReportFile>.*?)\.'){
            $ReportFile=$Matches.ReportFile
        }
    $OutputFile = "{0}\{1}_{2}_{3}.txt" -f  $InPC,$File.BaseName,$ReportFile,++$RepNum
    $Report | Add-Content $OutputFile
}
# Remove-Item $File.FullName
}
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of a file with (at least) two reports in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to use Regular Expressions to

- read in the file with -raw parameter and
- split the file at the marker `END OF REPORT` into sections
- use the `'SPEC #: RX:(?<ReportFile>.*?)\.'` with a named capture group to extract the `string`

## Edit adapted to PowerShell v2

```
## Q:\Test\2019\09\12\SO_57911471.ps1
$InPC = 'C:\Users\path' # 'Q:\Test\2019\09\12\' # 

ForEach($File in Get-ChildItem -Path $InPC -Filter *.txt){
    $RepNum=0
    ForEach($Report in (((Get-Content $File.FullName) -join "`n") -split 'END OF REPORT\r?\n?' -ne '')){

        if ($Report -match 'SPEC #: RX:(?<ReportFile>.*?)\.'){
            $ReportFile=$Matches.ReportFile
        }
        $OutputFile = "{0}\{1}_{2}_{3}.txt" -f  $InPC,$File.BaseName,$ReportFile,++$RepNum
        $Report | Add-Content $OutputFile
    }
    # Remove-Item $File.FullName
}
```

This construed sample text:

```
## Q:\Test\2019\09\12\SO_57911471.txt
I have a script here that looks for a delimiter in a text file with several reports in it.  
In the middle of the data of each page there is - 
SPEC #: RX:string1.  
I want that string to be saved as the filename.
END OF REPORT

I have a script here that looks for a delimiter in a text file with several reports in it.  
In the middle of the data of each page there is - 
SPEC #: RX:string2.  
I want that string to be saved as the filename.
END OF REPORT
```

yields:

```
> Get-ChildItem *string* -name
SO_57911471_string1_1.txt
SO_57911471_string2_2.txt
```

The added ReportNum is just a precaution in case the string could not be grepped.

Comment: Thank you very much, that's very helpful in understanding whats happening. I'm using PS2.0 sadly which doesn't understand -raw.

I've made the following changes but it's not working. I'm hoping it's just a syntax error. (posted in OP)

Comment: The general PowerShell Tag is meant for the mainstream, not an ancient one, please tag precisely first hand. See changed Answer.

Comment: Nicely done. As an aside: it occurred to me that you can speed up the v2 workaround for the lack of `-Raw` by using `-ReadCount 0`, because that reads all lines at once and returns them as an array, instead of the letting the pipeline collect the individually emitted lines in an array afterwards: `(Get-Content -ReadCount 0 $File.FullName) -join "\`n"`

Comment: I understand and apologize LotPings. I wasn't aware my work VM had 2.0 on it until it barked at the usage of -raw